# Cannot convert value of type StructName<X> to expected argument type 'X'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, decodable

I am passing a generic Decodable struct with parameter. Here is the struct code ..

```
struct NameStruct<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    
  // properties of the struct with property..

    let values: [T]

// coding keys here.
    
}
```

Then I am trying pass it like this way into the view..

```
 func property(NameStruct: T) {
        ImageView.setImage(backdropPath: NameStruct.imageName)
   }
```

viewModel..

```
var value: StructName<Struct>? {
        
       
    }
```

Then I am trying to configure  it with dequeueReusableCell function..

```
        let listValues = viewModel.value
        cell.property(NameStruct: listValues)
        return cell
```

But I got error ..

Cannot convert value of type 'NameStruct?' to expected argument type 'Struct'..

I am not sure . How can I pass it like generic.

Comment: Don't use generics if you don't understand how they work, simplify your code by making your types non-generic. For instance in `func property(NameStruct: T)` the  NameStruct is just an argument name and not a type so it has no relevance to your struct with the same name and the compiler has no idea what T is in that function declaration.

Comment: I am passing the type [T] like this way  for instance NameStruct <foo>

Comment: Let me try the way you mentioned .